# Children inherit parents appearance

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, containers, onpaint

I have created a simple custom panel using [ContainerControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx) as my base. I've added custom properties to create borders and gradient backgrounds. If I override OnPaint and OnPaintBackground all child controls of the parent inherit the gradient and border styles. As a work around I have used the parents BackgroundImage property which works fine but has a few random quirks. There has to be a better way of approaching this issue but I have found no solution. Are there any Window API functions via Interop or other C# methods to fix this? If so please provide an example.

**EDIT!** Here is the style being copied (ugly example but makes the point):

[image]

**EDIT 2!** Here is a simple hard-coded ContainerControl without all the properties, designer attributes, etc.

```
public class Container : ContainerControl
{
    protected override void OnPaintBackground( PaintEventArgs e )
    {
        using ( var brush = new LinearGradientBrush( e.ClipRectangle, Color.Red, Color.Blue, LinearGradientMode.Vertical ) )
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle( brush, e.ClipRectangle );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I don't think this should happen. Can you post your `OnPaint()` and `OnPaintBackground()` overrides?

Comment: Is `label2` a standard `Label` control or another custom control?

Comment: Are you getting this effect on the child control immediately after you drag/add them to the container, or after you set the background of the child control to be transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `Label` control is created with its `BackColor` property set to `Color.Transparent`, it will end up calling its parent's `OnPaintBackground()` implementation.

If you modify Jon's example like this:

```
var label = new Label { 
    Text = "Label",
    Location = new Point(20, 50),
    BackColor = Color.Transparent
};
```

Then you will reproduce the issue.

There is an easy workaround, however. The problem comes from the way you're creating the linear gradient brush. Since you're passing `e.ClipRectangle` to its constructor, the shape of the gradient will vary depending on the control being rendered (container or label). On the other hand, if you pass the [ClientRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) of the container, then the gradient will always have the same shape and the result should be what you're looking for:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle,
           Color.Red, Color.Blue, LinearGradientMode.Vertical)) {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Been struggling with why my child controls are painting with the same border as the form for while, it was because they were transparent. I just set them to the same back colour as the form and that sorted it for me. Glad you posted this! (working on a form with rounded corners and my buttons / image boxes ended up with the same border)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the properties on control create/load

Then "INVALIDATE" the control to force a redraw of the control

Comment: This didn't work. All of the children of the ContainerControl were redrawn with the parents gradient. If I set a child controls background to transparent I don't want the style of the parent ContainerControl copied.

Comment: if you are setting the child controls background to transparent, the parent controls style will show... that is how it works... unless you want a specific background... in that case specify it (example white)

Comment: are you putting the container inside another container?

Comment: Yes I want it to truly be transparent... Not hey set it to transparent but from Microsoft: Hey! that doesn't make sense! Lets make it inherit its parent! Who needs transparency!!! HAHAHAHA

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this simply on my Windows 7 machine - which suggests it may be one of the properties you've set in the designer. Short but complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class GradientContainer : ContainerControl
{
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.ClipRectangle, 
                       Color.Red, Color.Blue, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle);
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var label = new Label { 
            Text = "Label",
            Location = new Point(20, 50)
        };
        var container = new GradientContainer {
            Size = new Size(200, 200),
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
            Controls = { label }
        };        

        Form form = new Form {
            Controls = { container },
            Size = new Size(300, 300)
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    } 
}
```

And the result:

[image: Label has no gradient]